# Open subgroups $V\subset U$ of profinite group such that the index $[U:V]$ is divisible by $p$.

Tags: group-theory, group-cohomology, galois-cohomology

Let $G$ be a profinite group of $p$-cohomological dimension, $cd_p(G)\neq 0,\infty$. Consider an open subgroup $U\leq G$. Does there exist an open subgroup $V\leq U$ such that its index, $[U:V]$ is divisible by $p$?

Thanks!